# Could the UK government be prosecuted for their role in aiding and abetting war crimes in Gaza?

Tags: united-kingdom, israel, war-crime, gaza

Just came across this:

[Prime Minister warned of intention to prosecute UK government officials for complicity in war crimes in Gaza](https://www.icjpalestine.com/2023/10/14/prime-minister-warned-of-intention-to-prosecute-uk-government-officials-for-complicity-in-war-crimes-in-gaza/)

I don't want to rely solely on what they say on their page to assess the seriousness of the potential prosecution of the UK government.

They say:

> this could lead to UK government officials being prosecuted for war
> crimes by Scotland Yard.

Is this a serious threat to the UK government? Could they really be taken to court for such a reason, or is that not enough to start a court case and prosecution?

Comment: "prosecuted for war crimes by Scotland Yard."  This line suggests that the story is nonsense, as "Scotland Yard" doesn't lead proscutions.  That is a matter for the director of public prosecutions.  The standard for criminal prosecution is high, and the prospect for a successful conviction is here would, prima facie be very low.  So as Fizz says, this is probably fantasy.

Comment: But apparently I was mistaken in my first comment. They did some investigating of Saudi Arabia, which [nearly] triggered a diplomatic row https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/apr/02/met-police-examine-allegations-saudi-arabia-war-crimes-yemen Although the investigation appears to have been limited to "scoping", which is not much at all, probably.

Comment: I know this isn't official opinion, but he mentioned the same point at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKFSlb4cObs&t=520

Comment: A shallow basic point is that government officials can be prosecuted for war crimes, but governments cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked claim is that:

> International Centre of Justice for Palestinians (ICJP) has written a
> notice of intention to prosecute UK government officials, for aiding
> and abetting war crimes in Gaza.
>
> Officials could be held individually criminally liable for their role
> in aiding and abetting war crimes.
>
> The notice has been handed over to Scotland Yard’s War Crimes Unit,
> who have requested evidence relating to war crimes in the region.
> London 14 October 2023- The International Centre of Justice for
> Palestinians (ICJP) has issued Prime Minister Rishi Sunak with a stark
> warning that UK government officials could be individually liable for
> their role in aiding and abetting Israeli war crimes. Sunak has been
> issued with the notice of intention to prosecute UK government
> officials, for their role in providing military, economic and
> political support to Israel, which has aided Israel’s perpetration of
> war crimes.

Thus, basically, a non-profit in the U.K. aligned with one of the parties in the Israel-Hamas conflict wrote a letter to a law enforcement official in the U.K. stating that they think that the conduct of certain government officials in the U.K. government amount to war crimes.

There is no indication that any government official finds that these allegations are credible or they intend to take any action.

> Is this a serious threat to the UK government?

No.

> Could they really be taken to court for such a reason, or is that not
> enough to start a court case and prosecution?

A random non-profit doesn't get to make the call. Scotland Yard doesn't get to make the call.

Even if Scotland Yard did an investigation and found allegations to be substantiated, the decision would rest with the public prosecutors in the U.K. (i.e. the director of public prosecutions (DPP)), not its national law enforcement officers.

The officials in charge of deciding who is charged with crimes in the U.K. ultimately reports to the Prime Minister and his cabinet (who in turn, in theory, report to the King of England).

This story is a nothing burger that vastly exaggerates its importance.

Answer (score 1):

UK government officials, including the prime minister, can be investigated by a UK police force and can be prosecuted by the director of public prosecutions (DPP).

As a, perhaps trivial, example, [Boris Johnson was fined while prime minister](https://news.sky.com/story/boris-johnson-fined-prime-minister-apologises-after-receiving-fixed-penalty-notice-for-lockdown-breaking-party-12588712).

However, for an investigation by Scotland Yard, of an official, there would have to be substantial and credible evidence of a crime under UK law or under [International law covered by treaties to which the UK is a party](https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/war-crimes/what-is-a-war-crime). It isn't obvious that such evidence exists to the extent needed.

Comment: There is likely a difference between “private” actions of someone in government and actions of the government itself. In this case, they could sue Johnson for breaking lockdown rules. They couldn’t sue the government for producing these rules.

Comment: Important note: since Parliament has sovereign immunity they could force Scotland Yard to drop all investigations in the worst case scenario by passing a 1-page law directing them to do so.